This site tolerates the following users writing answers in comments
For the purpose of clarity and transparency, and to avoid unnecessary and futile flags adding to moderator workload, this post is to announce that the following users are tolerated by this community in posting their answers in comments:

Conifold (because of their notable excellent contributions, and the fact that they've been answering in comments for years)

Otherwise, this site follows StackExchange policy that comments should not be used for answers (see the moderator answer here: Can moderators clarify whether this site allows answers in comments?).

1. Moderators, please add to the above list as needed.

I'm somewhat indifferent to the whole "answers in comments" debate. But I strongly object to calling out specific users, unless 1) there's a persistent and continuing pattern of behaviour, 2) you've used a custom flag to highlight their pattern of behaviour to moderators and moderators didn't seem to do much about it, and 2.a) you've possibly followed up with the mods via a non-identifying Meta post or used the contact form to escalate to SE staff, and crucially 3) the behaviour of the individual is harmful enough that it warrants a public call-out. #1 applies here, and maybe #2, but not #3.

SE's moderating principle roughly boils down to: The community moderates content (to a large degree). Elected moderators moderate users (and exceptions and more egregious rule violations). Regular users can downvote or vote to close or vote to delete content, but if you see a user displaying a pattern of behaviour, that's something for moderators to deal with, not something to take into your own hands (but you can potentially use flags to make them aware of such patterns, as appropriate).

The conversation in your previous post also boiled down to talking about this user, but that was a much more appropriate post because it focused on content and how moderators responded to flags, i.e. "[This answer in comment] was flagged twice, but declined both times". Maybe my earlier comments don't apply exactly in that context, but I still largely stand behind those. The takeaway from that post should be less "make an exception for this user" and more: answers in comments are discouraged, but that isn't enforced super strictly.

The policy isn't as formalised as "this user's answer-in-comments are tolerated". It's more like: Here's a comment flag, but it provides some useful information and links, and it's posted by a user in good standing, so the flag is declined. And also: this user has a pattern of posting answers in comments, but those comments may be more useful than not useful, and they provide good contributions otherwise, so they aren't suspended. Also note, answers in comments may be discouraged, but e.g. "a link to a related question" is encouraged, and they often provide links, so that may blur the line.

"This behaviour is tolerated" doesn't translate to "we should encourage people to take advantage of it". It's like the difference between the government not throwing people in prison for using drugs without causing harm to anyone else, versus the government passing out fliers telling people which buildings you can use drugs within without being punished. If they make that an official policy, that's more them playing favourites and potentially giving permission for harmful behaviour, whereas judging things on a case-by-case basis can stay focused on harm reduction, as intended.

@NotThatGuy IOW, if it ain't broke, don't fix it? :D

I'm surprised no one takes leads from Comments to create Answers. C'mon, let's have some opportunism here!

Speaking for myself, I have sometimes given a short answer in the comments to a question. It is either because I think the question is very simple and does not merit a longer answer, or because the question does merit a long answer but I lack the knowledge or the time to provide it. In the latter case I may feel that I can contribute by making one or two pithy points and I am happy for others to pick them up and work them into a longer answer.

You say:

You, and the downvotes, have convinced me that I have misunderstood the approach being taken.

Perhaps the community should try to understand you and your motivations better. It seems to me that you are attempting to, as a non-moderator, establish a list of who is permitted to use comments to answer questions, and thereby establish a clear line between who is sanctioned, and who can be flagged. If I'm wrong about that, please let me know.
However, having been hanging around here for awhile now, I'm not sure that anything like this proposal would work without the enforcement of the moderators, and generally, the moderators are rather tolerant in policing comments because a strict policy towards comments seems like it might do more harm than good. While there is sometimes some petty squabbling in the comments (I've been there a few times myself, in fact), I do see quite a lot of good comments that either enrich the answer in someway (sometimes by pushing back on premises, etc.) or create some minimum amount of comity.
In fact, the moderators on this site are pretty laissez-faire in regards to affecting change on content, partially because they are volunteers and do it at their leisure, and partially because this community is rather tolerant of dissent. Unlike mathematics or physics, for instance, metaphilosophical differences arise that make it difficult to enforce a one-right-way, though a lot of people over the last few years have clamored for more enforcement.
Whatever the metasite's policy, I would consider it a great loss to the community if Mr. Conifold's or Sig. Allegranza's were removed. They often provide better quality answers in comments than others in full-fledged responses given their obvious philosophical professional expertise. But the idea that there is a site-sanctioned list of personae gratae probably wouldn't float around here because it's tough to get anyone to agree on much of anything around here, a feature rather than a bug of philosophical discourse.
So, on behalf of the moderators, all of whom seem to understand that there's a lot of libertarian freewill at play at this site, I would simply suggest that if you find any particular comment offensive or inappropriate you flag it, and otherwise allow the moderators a dispensation of sort to exercise executive prerogative to manage the comments as they see fit. It's not that your straight-laced approach isn't a good approach to management, but rather, it seems at odds with the current culture which has been set by many long years of established laissez-faire management. Until the moderators themselves take a more stringent and active tone in management, you might finding yourself getting frustrated over a lack of leverage in the situation.
As for your contributions, continue the good work!

The last para is incongruous — this question is about comments that are good enough to be answers. Not the — more usual — problem of inappropriate/offensive ones. The rest +1. For this issue, Phil has already exemplified the way — answerify the comment

@ScottRowe Hmmm. That phrase never once occurred to me in relation to this site, but is certainly the best characterization of trying to craft some sort of community with collective action here. The only collective action PhilSE is capable of is the collective action implemented in source code. :D

Another contributing factor (excluding Conifold and others who are similar) is the psychological difference between answering in comments and answering in the preferred format. Comments can't be downvoted while answers can. As anyone who has been downvoted can attest, the negative points are "hurtful". Comments never have negative points so they are "safer".

That's certainly one motivation. Another is that someone like Conifold, who has contributed a tremendous amount of energy to the activity, can assist users (who may not be interested in the "game" of answering and scoring) in a quick way which is better than no response at all, from the perspective of the person who posted the question.

@JD I agree. I should have excluded users like Conifold and point out that this just a contributing factor as to why others answer in comments. I've edited my response. Thanks!

@JD As to Conifold specifically, he obviously has vast knowledge and more crucially puts very exacting standards on his own answers.  This means that if his answer is not going to be in the very good to outstanding contribution he more and more tends to avoid making it.  [Notice that his exceptional answers are mostly from 5-6 years ago]. Should we ban/restrict him? I would have thought that ludicrous. Evidently not this questioner. There could be technical and non technical solutions (if we insist on them) (1/2)

Technical could be like: Users with over 15K rep can answer in comments Non-technical: It is a norm on this site that good answers in comments can be copied into a CW answer

Yes comments in answers subvert the democratic process. As does VTC — a downvote costs a -1, a VTC costs nothing and so gets misused. IMHO this misuse happens much more here than on other sites. I mention this because you mention "hurt" — which hurts more one downvote among two upvotes (say) or accumulating closevotes? On askubuntu directing a VTC to a SU question or on law directing a VTC toward a politics question is not analogously hurtful. Also the same parties cribbing about comment-answers are the misusers of the VTC.

No, tolerating something inexplicitly is different from allowing it explicitly.
And nothing about this is personal or specific to any user.
If anyone wants the same treatment, they'll get it. Anyone continuously posting answers as comments will annoy the heck out of everyone, be asked by moderators to change to questions, but moderators cannot be asked to follow up on each such case.
